# How to set a fixed fill in geom_col equivalent to geom_bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar, geom-col

Consider the following code that should be making two identical bar charts, except for axis labels. The data.frame `dat` is representative of the kind of data I have, just colour responses. It would seem a good idea to use those colours in plotting.

```
colOrder = c('green', 'blue', 'red', 'orange', 'purple')
dat <- data.frame(q = rep(c('red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'), c(1:5)))

# using geom_bar
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(q, levels = colOrder) )) +
    geom_bar(fill = colOrder)

#using geom_col
dc <- as.data.frame(table(dat$q))
names(dc) <- c('q', 'n')
ggplot(dc, aes(x = factor(q, levels = colOrder), y = n )) +
    geom_col(fill = colOrder)
```

Why are these plots not identical? The `geom_col` seems to be filling using the colour order in `dc$q` while geom_bar correctly takes `colOrder` as requested. Am I missing something in `geom_col` documentation? bug?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you pass the fill colors as an argument to `geom_bar/col`. Doing so the colors are assigned to the categories according to the order as they appear in the datasets used by `geom_bar/col`. While `geom_col` uses the data as is, `geom_bar` first computes the counts via `stat="count"` and reorders the data according to the variable mapped on `x`. As a result, when adding the vector of fill colors to these datasets, you get different colors for some categories.

You can see this clearly by using `layer_data()` which allows to retrieve the data used by a `geom` layer under the hood:

```r
colOrder = c('green', 'blue', 'red', 'orange', 'purple')
dat <- data.frame(q = rep(c('red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'), 1:5))

library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(q, levels = colOrder) )) +
  geom_bar(fill = colOrder)

dc <- as.data.frame(table(dat$q))
names(dc) <- c('q', 'n')
p2 <- ggplot(dc, aes(x = factor(q, levels = colOrder), y = n )) +
  geom_col(fill = colOrder)

layer_data(p1, 1)[c("x", "y", "group", "fill")]
#>   x y group   fill
#> 1 1 3     1  green
#> 2 2 4     2   blue
#> 3 3 1     3    red
#> 4 4 2     4 orange
#> 5 5 5     5 purple

layer_data(p2, 1)[c("x", "y", "group", "fill")]
#>   x y group   fill
#> 1 2 4     2  green
#> 2 1 3     1   blue
#> 3 4 2     4    red
#> 4 5 5     5 orange
#> 5 3 1     3 purple
```

As is evident for `geom_bar` aka the first plot the data is ordered according to `colOrder` after the statistical transformation, whereas for `geom_col` aka the second plot the data is not reordered.

If you want the same or consistent colors then map on the `fill` aesthetic and set your colors via `scale_fill_manual` (or if you have a column with color names as in your example by using `scale_fill_identity()`):

```
p3 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(q, levels = colOrder) )) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = q)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colOrder)

p4 <- ggplot(dc, aes(x = factor(q, levels = colOrder), y = n )) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = q)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colOrder)

library(patchwork)

(p1 + p2) / (p3 + p4)
```

[image]